# Git - Refraining from pushing some local changes

Tags: git

While working on my project's user interface, I test it locally. Thus, I want to be able to uncomment some remote includes in the HTML head, work for a bit, and then push the changes without the uncomments, which are there just to make testing it locally faster. What's the best way to do this with git?

Comment: One thing you could do, is just never commit that change. Always add changes (in that file at least) using `git add -p`, or unstage that line before you commit.

Comment: Is there any cleaner, more usable solution than that? Something like a named stash entry that I could just remove before each commit and apply after each commit would be ideal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a separate branch off of your `master` that just has these lines uncommented, e.g.,

```
git checkout -b testing master
# edit foo/bar/baz.html
git commit -a -m "Enable local testing optimizations."
```

And then leave this branch alone.  You would rarely have to touch it.  Later you're doing some work you want to test, so you check in your feature ...

```
# hack hack hack
git commit -m "Feature complete."
```

...and then (temporarily) merge in your testing changes.

```
git merge testing
```

Assuming you're not modifying the headers, this will rarely cause any conflicts and should merge cleanly.  You finish your testing, and then you can

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

to throw away the merge commit, leaving your tree where the `HEAD` points to your "Feature complete." commit.

Occasionally, you can rebase the `testing` branch against `master`, or re-work it to deal with any changes from that portion.

---

Another option is to maintain your changes simply in a `.patch` file.  Then ...

```
# Feature complete!
# Apply testing code... 
git apply testing.patch
# Test...
git apply -R testing.patch
# Remove testing code
```

Same idea, but handled with a separate patch file.  A little simpler, maybe allowing a little bit less discipline, but also maybe a bit riskier.

---

You might also want to write an `update` hook (see [githooks(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)) to ensure that you never push a change that includes this testing patch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the file to a commit.  Add & commit only the files with changes you want to push.  For example...

```
Uncomment remote includes in foo.html
edit file1.html
edit file2.html

git add file1.html
git add file2.html
git commit -m "added feature"
git push origin master
```

The changes made to foo.html will not be pushed.

---

If you want to blow away your local changes to a file, the use `git checkout` ...

```
git checkout path\to\foo.html
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using client-side hooks to automate uncommenting on post-checkout and commenting on pre-commit?

If the comments that you're changing aren't always the same, this may not be the best solution.

For info on Git's hooks, see [Section 7.3 of the *Pro Git* book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html).